# Use a column_property (with a calculation) to define a relationship in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys, relationship

I have the following setup:

A set of competitions taking place at given dates, global competitors with birthdates that can be registered for some of these competitions, age classes defined for each competition and at last the registration of a specific competitor for a specific competition. These registrations should finally contain the correct age class. I could achieve this with e.g. hybrid_property, but then I'd run into the N+1 issue. My goal is, to get the registrations eagerly loaded with one large joined query, including the age classes.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, ForeignKey, Integer, Date, select, func, cast, and_
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base, declared_attr
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker, relationship, column_property, joinedload, Load, foreign, remote

import transaction
import inflection
import datetime

import logging
logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.engine').setLevel(logging.INFO)

engine = create_engine('sqlite://')
db = scoped_session(sessionmaker())

db.configure(bind=engine)


DBModel = declarative_base()
DBModel.metadata.bind = engine


class Competition(DBModel):
    __tablename__ = 'competitions'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = Column(Date, nullable=False)


class Competitor(DBModel):
    __tablename__ = 'competitors'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    birthdate = Column(Date, nullable=False)


class AgeClass(DBModel):
    __tablename__ = 'age_classes'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    competition_id = Column(ForeignKey(Competition.id), nullable=False)
    min = Column(Integer, nullable=False)

    competition = relationship(Competition)


class Registration(DBModel):
    __tablename__ = 'registrations'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    competition_id = Column(ForeignKey(Competition.id), nullable=False)
    competitor_id = Column(ForeignKey(Competitor.id), nullable=False)

    competition = relationship(Competition)
    competitor = relationship(Competitor)

    age = column_property(select([cast((func.julianday(Competition.date) - func.julianday(Competitor.birthdate)) / 365.2425, Integer)]).
                          where(and_(Competition.id == competition_id,
                                     Competitor.id == competitor_id)).
                          correlate_except())

    age_class_id = column_property(select([AgeClass.id]).
                                   where(and_(AgeClass.competition_id == competition_id,
                                              AgeClass.min <= age)).
                                   order_by(AgeClass.min.desc()).limit(1).
                                   correlate_except(AgeClass))

#    age_class = relationship(AgeClass, viewonly=True)
#    age_class = relationship(AgeClass, foreign_keys=[age_class_id], viewonly=True)
#    age_class = relationship(AgeClass, primaryjoin=AgeClass.id == remote(age_class_id), viewonly=True)
    age_class = relationship(AgeClass, primaryjoin=foreign(AgeClass.id) == remote(age_class_id), viewonly=True)


DBModel.metadata.create_all()

with transaction.manager:
    competition = Competition(date=datetime.date(2020, 2, 9))
    competitor = Competitor(birthdate=datetime.date(2000, 2, 9))
    db.add(AgeClass(competition=competition, min=6))
    db.add(AgeClass(competition=competition, min=10))
    db.add(Registration(competition=competition, competitor=competitor))

query = db.query(Registration).options(joinedload(Registration.competition, innerjoin=True),
                                       joinedload(Registration.competitor, innerjoin=True),
                                       joinedload(Registration.age_class, innerjoin=True),
                                       Load(Registration).raiseload('*'))
print([x.age_class for x in query.first()])
```

The first two versions of the age_class attribute lead to the error message

> sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Registration.age_class - there are no foreign keys linking these tables.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin' expression.

Hence I tried to specify a primary join condition, which gives me the following error message for versions 3 and 4:

> sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Relationship Registration.age_class could not determine any unambiguous local/remote column pairs based on join condition and remote_side arguments.  Consider using the remote() annotation to accurately mark those elements of the join condition that are on the remote side of the relationship.

Is there any chance to get this going or am I trying to do something impossible here? Or is there another way to approach this question?